# hls segmenter that accepts a list of keyframes to segment on

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, mediastreamsegmenter

I am creating variant h.264 streams using x264.  Using a qpfile (http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Settings#qpfile) I ensure that my variant streams have common keyframes.  However, they can have other keyframes that differ between streams if the encoder optimizer wants because I do not specify every frame of the video in the qpfile.

Are there any segmenters available that will allow me to specify which keyframes are allowed to start a new segment?  Otherwise, if I segment only by target duration, it is likely that my variant streams will be segmented out of sync.

I am asking because I want to add hls to my current encoding process without changing it.  I have not seen any segmenters that allow this, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no such tool.

It might not be too difficult to make your own segmenter that would read a qpfile that only has the common keyframes, but it is work.